# flash as3 equivalent of processing's popmatrix() and pushmatrix() - or...storing a transform matrix

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, matrix, transform, processing

I'm trying to convert a processing sketch to a flash as3 file, and I'm getting hung up on two of processing's commands - pushMatrix() and popMatrix() - can anyone tell me how to convert these in flash?

Essentially I just need to store the matrix of lines I've drawn so far and draw a new line, and this gets done recursively. Here's my code:

```
var theta;
var xpos:Number = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,draw)

function draw(e:Event) {


graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xf1eee5, 1, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.SQUARE);

  var a = (mouseX / stage.stageWidth) * 90;
trace("a: " + a);
  var theta = degreesToRadians(a);
  graphics.moveTo(stage.stageWidth/2,stage.stageHeight);
  graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth/2,stage.stageHeight-150);
  branch(150);
  if (a <= 30){
    xpos+=3;
  } else {

  }
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees:Number):Number {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}


function branch(h) {
  // Each branch will be 2/3rds the size of the previous one
  h *= 0.66;

  // All recursive functions must have an exit condition!!!!
  // Here, ours is when the length of the branch is 2 pixels or less
  if (h > 2) {

    /* HASN'T BEEN CONVERTED TO FLASH AS3 YET
    pushMatrix();    // Save the current state of transformation (i.e. where are we now)
    rotate(theta);   // Rotate by theta
    line(0, 0, 0, -h);  // Draw the branch
    translate(0, -h); // Move to the end of the branch
    branch(h);       // Ok, now call myself to draw two new branches!!
    popMatrix();     // Whenever we get back here, we "pop" in order to restore the previous matrix state

    // Repeat the same thing, only branch off to the "left" this time!
    pushMatrix();
    rotate(-theta);
    line(0, 0, 0, -h);
    translate(0, -h);
    println(h);
    branch(h);
    popMatrix();
    */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues regarding the differences in drawing api's.

The first, flash does not keep track of transformation matrices unless you are drawing into multiple sprites on the display hierarchy.  This would not be recommended as each successful recursion would create at least two display objects and clutter the display hierarchy.

The second, more or less, due to the first, is that flash also does not automatically apply a transformation to draw methods, unless using multiple display objects as described above.

The following code would roughly do what you need.  I've played around with your snippet, but am unsure if the render created on my side matches the algorithm you were using with processing.

```
private var matrices:Vector.<Matrix>;
private var matrix:Matrix;

public function Main()
{
    matrices = new Vector.<Matrix>();
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.identity();
}

private function pushMatrix():void
{
    matrices.push(matrix.clone());
}

private function popMatrix():void
{
    matrix = matrices.pop();
}
```

Within your draw method, you will have to maintain two points, origin and target.  Each represents the transformed point based on the current matrix.

```
var origin:Point;
var target:Point;

pushMatrix();
matrix.rotate(theta);

origin = matrix.transformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
target = matrix.transformPoint(new Point(0, -h));

graphics.moveTo(origin.x, origin.y);
graphics.moveTo(target.x, target.y);

...
```

There are basic optimizations that you can perform to the algorithm.  Reuse of existing points would defiantly help out.

I do not have processing installed, but if you could link a video that represents this particular algorithm, it could help others understand what your aiming for.

Best of luck!